# Type Has No Subscript Members?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, nscoding, subscript

I get the error "Type 'Ship' has no subscript members when I try to do:

```
var coor = ship[index]
```

I tried to do

```
var coor = ship?[index] as? Coordinate
```

But I get this error: "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'Ship'"

Here's my `Ship` class:

```
import Foundation

class Ship: NSObject, NSCoding {

    var shipCoors: [Coordinate]?

    var count: Int {
        var count = 0
        for _ in shipCoors! {
            count++
        }
        return count
    }

    init(shipCoors: [Coordinate]) {
        self.shipCoors = shipCoors
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.shipCoors = decoder.decodeObjectForKey("shipCoors") as? [Coordinate]
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encodeObject(shipCoors, forKey: "shipCoors")
    }
}
```

The `Coordinate` class is also of type `NSObject, NSCoding`, etc...
The objects seem to be in the array when I load them (from `NSUserDefaults`)? How do I get them out?!

Comment: You want `ship.shipCoors?[index]`

Comment: Your `count` property getter can just be `return shipCoors?.count ?? 0` btw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a subscript to your `Ship` object to return an optional `Coordinate`:

```
subscript(index: Int) -> Coordinate? {
    guard let coordinate = shipCoors?[index] else {
        return nil
    }
    return coordinate
}
```

`shipCoors` is declared as `[Coordinate]?` (an optional array), so there's a risk a `Ship` won't have an array in `shipCoors`.  In this case I return `nil`, but you can return whatever you want instead.

Answer (score 9):

Had similar issue in Swift 3

```
Type '() -> [myObject]' has no subscript members
```

In my case, It was a simple case of not adding the brackets to the function-call "()". school boy error.

i.e. the below code was the culprit

```
dataModel.myFunction
```

Solved with     `dataModel.myFunction()`

Comment: thanks for posting this answer. One can be out of school for a long time and still make this error (it seems).

Comment: my pleasure, i face such issues on a daily basis :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly add subscripting support to the class in order to use the subscript syntax, e.g. `ship[index]`.

Here are the docs that cover subscripting and how to add subscripting to your class:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html

Answer (score 0):

For my code:

```
func takeN(_ numbers: Int...) -> [Int]{
    var intArray : [Int] = []
    for n in numbers{
        intArray.append[n]

    }
    return intArray
}
```

I was getting the following error:

> error: type '(Int) -> ()' has no subscript members
>           intArray.append[n]

It means the `append` function doesn't use subscripts or `[]`!

changing the line of

```
intArray.append[n]
```

to:

```
intArray.append(n)
```

would resolve the entire issue!